# Track multiple directories with etckeeper

Tags: debian, git, debian-jessie, etckeeper

I'm trying to provide a solution to use etckeeper as a keeper of multiple locations (directories). I'm using Debian 8. With the default config etckeeper "watches" the /etc directory but I want to have /etc and /opt directories monitored.
If I use -d flag will I have repo for each of directory mentioned or one single repo?
Thank you for any help.